# How can I spy on/capture packets from JDWP to the Android VM?

Tags: android, jdwp

I'm working on a Java debugger that uses JDWP, talking to the Android VM.

I'm most interested in going from the desktop to the Emulator, and not on the device.
I know that on the device, it's a whole different matter,
so that's why I want to concentrate going from the desktop to the Emulator.

I'm finding that some common JDWP packet commands get 'ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED' errors,
so it would be a lot easier if I could spy on, or be able to capture JDWP
packets coming from known working debuggers, to get a better idea of what
combination of commands they are sending.  Being able to get the replies would be good too.

I looked at Wireshark and WinDump, but they all seem to be interface based,
and no matter what settings I've tried to use, I get nothing packet-wise.

My question is, is there any tool I can use for this?

Thanks!

Comment: I was under the impression this works via adb and that the two parts of adb talk to each other via a loopback TCP socket and to the emulator on loopback port 5555.  But it is possible some of it is now unix domain sockets - adbd to the vm on the device has always been unix domain.  Note that the source to adb is readily available - along with that for the DVM or ART.

Comment: For mine I do: 'adb jdwp' get the PID, then 'adb forward tcp:8000 jdwp:(PID)', but I guess other debuggers could get the port a different way.  I'm trying to look at the VM code, but it's going to take a long time to find the different bits of info that I need.

Comment: Here's one of many issues I'm trying to resolve.  I want to try to set a breakpoint, and that requires a Location object, and that has an "unsigned eight byte location", but when I try to do a LineTable command, with the ClassId and MethodId, it returns 'ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED'..

Comment: It seems you have the port identified, can't you tcpdump the loopback interface, filter on that port, and set a breakpoint in the debugger to see how it is done?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your replies.  I tried to use RawCap, set to capture everything on 127.0.0.1 Loopback, ran my app, that I know was using port 8000, and it looks like it captured everything, in both directions!  It saves everything to a .pcap file, and I can "read" it in Wireshark!  I just have to skip the whole TCP header to look at the data for each packet.  Thanks!

Comment: Great! Though I think all I've really done is encourage you to run with your original idea.

Answer (score 2):

I have a project on GitHub that allows you to "spy" on the JDWP traffic, I've developed it while I was working on the NetBeans debugger to help me analyze debugger related issues.

Have a look here:
https://github.com/kherink/jdwp-analyzer